# О народном неприятии формы НИ ПРИ ЧЕМ

Tags: фразеология, частица-не, ни

```
       — При чем тут я-то? Я тут НЕ при чем.  
       — Правильно: НИ при чем!
       — А это у меня отрицание.
```

1. О сочетании ***НИ ПРИ ЧЕМ***  написаны целые поэмы. Казалось бы, надо запомнить, как правильно, и точка! Записать и повторять каждый день, пока не выучишь.  Русский орфографический словарь: ***ни при чём.***
2. Может быть, **не понимают** правило? Но  мне думается, что не только в этом дело. Пользователи еще и **не хотят** это понимать. В нацкорпусе  280 примеров с ***НЕ,*** половина из них после 1956 года, а 90 примеров после 2000 года.

   ```
   Можно сказать, что частица НИ совмещает значения 
   усиления и отрицания, но ведь можно считать, что 
   это просто отрицание и писать частицу НЕ." Я 
   считаю, что это самый хороший ответ. Мне лично 
   больше нравится вариант НЕ при чём. И я так и 
   пишу )) 

   Я не филолог, а даже наоборот, математик, и мне 
   думается, что имеем отрицание для "при чем": — 
   При чем тут это? — Не при чем.

   НИ, как и объяснения его присутствия в этой 
   фразе, представляются  мне надуманными, 
   искусственными.
   ```
3. Кстати, нормированная **запись**  1956 года в словаре относится к таким сочетаниям: ***остался ни с чем, остался ни при чем, пропал ни за что.*** Это действительно похоже на усиление отрицания. Но ***быть ни при чем*** — это совсем другое значение. А в словаре РАН нет об этом информации. Есть в словаре [синонимов](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC&mode=slovari): ***остался ни при чем.***
4. Вопрос: Можно ли использовать отрицательную форму НЕ ПРИ ЧЕМ в сочетании ***быть ни при чем***?

Answer (score 1):

Не при чем -- абсолютно грамматичная конструкция, нацкорпус не даст соврать.
А вот грамматику "ни при чем" еще надо обосновывать. В языке полно похожих конструкций

```
Он пришел ни с чем.
Он был ни при чем. 
Он был ни о чем.
```

Откуда взялось это усиление отрицания без отрицания, вот о чем надо поискать статьи. Вообще смахивает на цельные словосочетания, типа

```
На небе было ни тучки
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня. Полно конструкций, это верно.  Повторяющийся союз НИ...НИ, например: ни то ни се, ни свет ни заря.  Примеров достаточно,  и это норма, как я считаю. Остался ни с чем, ни при чем  (1956 год) — это тоже вполне корректно. Но "быть ни при чем" — вот это уже сомнительно.  Как я думаю, здесь не  очень обоснованное расширение значения. И это уже творчество "новых" академиков.  Было бы правильно разрешить обе формы (отрицательную и усилительную) именно для этого сочетания.  Выбор по собственному усмотрению.